# можно ли создавать stored proc в MariaDB ver 5.5?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

На тестовой машине у меня установлен MySQL 8

На сервере стоит MariaDB версии 5.5.64
Server version: 5.5.64-MariaDB - MariaDB Server (из phpmyqdmin)
Пытаюсь на сервере создать простейшую stored proc.
Сервер пишет - что у меня какая то ошибка в конце в районе строки //
Пробовал и с delimeiter и без - результат один и тот же.

```
delimiter //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `spUpdate_board_stat`(IN  id_board_parm int)
begin

    # количество топиков в board
    select  count(*)
    into @cnt_topics
    from smf_boards B
             inner join smf_topics T
                        on T.id_board = B.id_board
    where B.id_board = id_board_parm;



    select  count(*)
    into @cnt_posts
    from smf_boards B
             inner join smf_messages M
                        on M.id_board = B.id_board
    where B.id_board = id_board_parm;

    select  M.id_msg
    into @last_msg_id
    from smf_boards B
             inner join smf_messages M
                        on M.id_board = B.id_board
    where B.id_board = id_board_parm
    order by M.id_msg desc limit 1;

    UPDATE smf_boards
    SET id_last_msg    = @last_msg_id,
        id_msg_updated = @last_msg_id,
        num_topics        = @cnt_topics,
        num_posts         = @cnt_posts,
        unapproved_posts  =  0,
        unapproved_topics =  0
    WHERE id_board = id_board_parm;

end //
```

Подскажите пожалуйста - были ли stored proc в MariaDB версии 5.5 ?
Если они были - где бы посмотреть пример stored proc ?

Answer (score 0):

Я пробовал создавать stored proc через phpmyadmin скопировав текст на вкладку SQL.

Оказалось что так это не работает.

При создании stored proc через phpmyadmin необходимо пользоваться специальной вкладкой Routines